# mark unchecked radio inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

Hey there here's the problem.
I have 3x3 table with radion input in each cell.
Each line has it's own name so it's possible to check only one radio in a row.
I've made jquery to checl if those 3 radio are selected. If yes, we go to the next page, if no, I have to select the line with no marked radios.
I've done the "yes" checking but have no idea about "no" statement.
Here's the code:

```
                            <div id="check-services" class="button">
                            <table>
                                <tr class="select-checkboxes">
                                    <td>Fahrschule Müssig Dresdner Straße 1 80993 München</td>
                                    <td class="radio-tab"><input name="radio-office-01" type="radio"/></td>
                                    <td class="radio-tab"><input name="radio-office-01" type="radio"/></td>
                                    <td class="radio-tab"><input name="radio-office-01" type="radio"/></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="select-checkboxes">
                                    <td>Fahrschule Müssig Straßbergerstraße 34 80809 München</td>
                                    <td class="radio-tab"><input name="radio-office-02" type="radio"/></td>
                                    <td class="radio-tab"><input name="radio-office-02" type="radio"/></td>
                                    <td class="radio-tab"><input name="radio-office-02" type="radio"/></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="select-checkboxes">
                                    <td>Fahrschule Müssig Goethestraße 66 80663 München</td>
                                    <td class="radio-tab"><input name="radio-office-03" type="radio"/></td>
                                    <td class="radio-tab"><input name="radio-office-03" type="radio"/></td>
                                    <td class="radio-tab"><input name="radio-office-03" type="radio"/></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>

    $('#check-services .button').click(function(){
    var officeOne = $('input[name="radio-office-01"]');
    var officeTwo = $('input[name="radio-office-02"]');
    var officeThree = $('input[name="radio-office-03"]');

    if($(officeOne && officeTwo && officeThree).is(':checked')){
        $(this).parents('#check-services').hide();
        $('#check-payment').show()
    }
    else{
        blablabla
    }
});
```

Comment: you have not done the "yes" checking

Comment: also, inputs should not have the same `name` attribute

Comment: Would you provide a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) link that I can see your code is working?

Comment: must have copied something wrong, here
http://jsfiddle.net/7hhpw565/

Answer (score 1):

I've doubt to understand your question correctly, but I wanna suggest the jquery's [.closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method.

As you can see [Here( jsFiddle )](http://jsfiddle.net/7hhpw565/2/) we now have the rows that there is no checked input on them.

Your mistake was your condition as @radonirina-maminiaina said. But there is also a better way:

```
if ( officeOne.is( ':checked' ) && officeTwo.is( ':checked' )
      && officeThree.is( ':checked' ) ) {

        alert('yes');

}
```

And for the rest of our way, we've checked each line of our table and give them some specific style ( you may want to do anything else with them ):

```
if ( !officeOne.is( ':checked' ) ) {

    officeOne.closest( 'tr' ).css('background-color', 'red' );

}
```

And the same for other rows. Full working code is on your [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7hhpw565/2/). Try to check some of them and submit it.

Hope to help.

Answer (score 0):

The selector that you use is not correct.

Use the following selector: `$('#check-services .button')`

And the way you check if the radio is checked or not is incorrect too.

This is the correct condition:

```
if($(officeOne).is(':checked') && $(officeTwo).is(':checked') && $(officeThree).is(':checked') )
```

Here's a demo to demonstrate the result: http://jsfiddle.net/2xn0gL7z/